# Limit the number of simultanious builds for a sub project

Tags: teamcity

I have a sub project in which I would like to ensure the build configurations in this sub project will never run at the same time.

All the build configurations are based on the same template and I have tried setting "limit the number of concurrent build to" 1 but this has no effect. I assume since this binds to the concrete build configuration and not the template.

I assumed I could set an agent requirement to limit the name to the build agent in a snapshot dependence but apparently agent requirements will not evaluate variables.

I also have a build configuration called All which has snapshot dependencies on all the build configurations in my sub project. Under snapshot dependencies settings I tried setting "Run on same build agent" but this could result in the build queue could run on "No agents". I assume because I started one build configuration manually. Then invoked all which confused Teamcity.

The only thing that works is hardcoding the agent name as a requirement but I'm not a fan of this solution. How can I limit simultanious builds across a sub project without hardcoding an agent name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is [Shared Resources](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Shared+Resources).
From official documentation:

> The Shared Resources build feature allows limiting concurrently
>   running builds using a shared resource, such as an external (to the CI
>   server) resource, e.g. test database, or a server with a limited
>   number of connections, etc.